# Batch file errors

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a batch file

```
@echo off
color 0a
:start
cls
echo "create" (create password)
echo "check" (check password)
echo.
set /p PROGRAM= What do you want to do?: 
goto %PROGRAM%
```

and I want to make it so if you don't enter "create" or "check" it gives you an invalid message and sends you back to the start of the program

(not looking for "if not defined". I am looking for if you type something other then "create" or "check")

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
color 0a
:start
cls
echo "create" (create password)
echo "check" (check password)
echo.
set /p PROGRAM= What do you want to do?: 
if "%PROGRAM%" == "create" goto create
if "%PROGRAM%" == "check" goto check
echo error message here
pause
goto start
```

i think thats pretty basic, not much explaination needed, but if you have questions, feel free to ask.